# Naming rows identically in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, double, row, names

I have a matrix which will hold results from a regression and I want to name the rows.

```
output_mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 6, ncol = 2)
colnames(output_mat)  <- c("Variable 1", "Variable 2")
row.names(output_mat) <- c("Significance","Standard Error","Residuals","Significance","Standard Error","Residuals")
```

Unfortunately, in the `View()`-command it appears as follows:

```
                Variable1   Variable2
Significance      NA        NA
Standard.Error    NA        NA
Residuals         NA        NA
Significance.1    NA        NA
Standard.Error.1  NA        NA
Residuals.1       NA        NA
```

I need to insert this table as screenshot. How can I stop R to add the continous number and the "." in the View()-Command?

If there is a more appropirate method to store the data/get the table screenshotted, please let me know!
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check it in console instead of `View`

Comment: Hi, yes in console it appears correctly. But I need the screenshot of ```View()``` to keep the layout (this table needs to be inserted in my master thesis).

Comment: there are other methods to get this as table.  Not sure why you need this way. il.e.e you can create a markdown file